# Clearing an array content and reactivity issues using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

A few years ago it was bad practice to do

```
array = [];
```

because if the array was referenced somewhere that reference wasn't updated or something like that.

The correct way was supposed to be `array.length = 0;`

Anyway, JavaScript has been updated now, and there's a framework called Vue.js

Vue does not catch  `array.length = 0;` so the property won't be reactive. But it does catch `array = [];`

Can we use `array = [];` now, or is JavaScript still broken?

Comment: vue.js is still broken

Comment: try learning javascript first instead of learning vuejs

Comment: well, react is much worse !

Comment: Lack of understanding or knowledge in the subject doesn't mean it's necessarily broken.

Comment: To clarify for others new to JavaScript, this question is very badly written and be careful when reading it. First, JavaScript is not broken. Second, JavaScript was not 'updated' to have Vue, it's simply a framework. Third, the 'losing reference if doing = [], is by design and is not something broken. Can't simply explain why it does that in this comment but learn about it please. As for the "if it's referenced somewhere" literally where you are using it is a reference. How JavaScript stores and references things is basic JS 101, and very very useful to FULLY understand. Read up asap.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Doing something like `myArray.splice(0)` will clear the content of the array and that will also be reactive:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      items: ["a", "b", "c"]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    flush() {
      this.items.splice(0);
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">

  <div v-for="i in items">{{i}}</div>

  <button @click="flush"> flush</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array: When you directly
> set an item with the index, e.g. vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue When
> you modify the length of the array, e.g. vm.items.length = newLength

From: *[Reactivity in Depth, For Arrays](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays)*

So, cleaning a reactive array:

```
yourArray.splice(0)
```